Trigger an action like installing application using dropdown list and button
I asked this before but got no results, so I am asking again. I made sure and searched, while also trying to own code (trial and error) to figure it out before posting. I am trying to create a kiosk or applet of some sort that will allow the an action to happen when an item is selected from the list then a button clicked. This could be anything like installing an application, or launching a console, or running a script. I have another one that uses button tied to functions, but it is getting crowded with a bunch of buttons so I figured the list would be cleaner.
Add-type -AssemblyName system.windows.forms
$formobject = [System.Windows.forms.form] 
$OfficeMenuForm=New-object $formobject
$OfficeMenuForm.clientsize= '750,500' #set the height and width
$OfficeMenuForm.text ='Office Installation Menu'
$OfficeMenuForm.backcolor='White'
$DefaultFont='Verdana,10'
$OfficeMenuForm.Font=$DefaultFont

#Build form
$labelobject = [System.Windows.Forms.Label]
$ComboBoxObject=[System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox]
$LabelTitle=New-Object $labelobject
$LabelTitle.Text='Make a selection from the dropdown menu then click the Install button'
$LabelTitle.AutoSize=$true
$LabelTitle.Location=New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$BtnObject= [System.Windows.Forms.Button]
$BtnInstall=New-Object $BtnObject
$BtnInstall.Text='Install'
$BtnInstall.AutoSize=$true
$BtnInstall.font='Verdana,10'
$BtnInstall.Location=New-Object System.Drawing.Point(550,250)
$DDLOffice=New-Object $ComboBoxObject
$DDLOffice.Width='300'
$DDLOffice.Location=New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,40)
#Add items to the dropdownlist
@('LTSC 2021 STD x64','LTSC 2021 STD+Project+Visio Std x64','LTSC 2021+Project 
STD')|ForEach-Object {[void]$DDLOffice.Items.Add($_)}
#Select default value
$DDLOffice.SelectedIndex=0

#lable to confirm selection
$LabelObject1=[System.Windows.Forms.Label]
$LabelOutPut=New-Object $LabelObject1
$LabelOutPut.Text="You selected: $Choice"
$LabelOutPut.AutoSize=$true
$LabelOutPut.location=new-object System.Drawing.Point (100,400)
#catch selection
$DDLOffice.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
$choice=$DDLOffice.SelectedItem
$LabelOutPut.Text="You selected: $Choice"
})
Function install{

if ($DDLOffice.SelectedIndex='2'){
start-process notepad.exe
}

}


$BtnInstall.Add_Click({Install})

#create an array to accept all the controls you want to appear on the form
$OfficeMenuForm.Controls.AddRange(@($LabelTitle,$BtnInstall,$DDLOffice,$LabelOutPut))
$OfficeMenuForm.showdialog() #displays the form
$OfficeMenuForm.dispose() #cleans up form


The issue with your code is using = (assignment) instead of -eq (equality comparison operator) in your install function, so simply:
function install {
    if ($DDLOffice.SelectedIndex -eq 2) {
        Start-Process notepad.exe
    }
}

Would fix your problem, you could also use a switch in this case:
function install {
    switch ($DDLOffice.SelectedIndex) {
        0 { Write-Host "do thing for index 0" }
        1 { Write-Host "do thing for index 1" }
        2 { Start-Process notepad }
    }
}


Wow, looks like I was heading in the right direction lol. I opted to use your "switch" code,  and that gave me what I want. Thanks for everything.
